# explorer.exe as the parent process in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, process, child-process

I am killing some tasks within `cmd` using following command:

```
taskkill /f /im software* /t
```

It does the job and kills all the tasks with that `IMAGENAME`; but, looking at what it gave me, I saw something interesting. Look below:

> ```
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 14712 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 12184 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 16344 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 6816 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 10656 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 14912 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 11908 (child process of PID 9068) has been terminated.
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 9068 (child process of PID 10060) has been terminated.
> ```

So, as expected, all the processes are attached to one centralize task `PID = 9068`. But then, that process is also a child process of `PID = 10060` which is the `PID` of `explorer.exe`. This job has no `GUI`. So I am surprised to see that it is a child process of `explorer`.

So, here's a question: What kind of processes will be under *explorer.exe* in *windows*?

#### *Update:*

***Question:*** If I want to avoid killing (using `taskkill`) any process that is directly a child process of *explorer.exe*, how would I approach that?

This is what I have so far. First we need to get the `pid` for *explorer.exe*:

```
TASKLIST /NH /FI  "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"
```

Then, I am thinking of writing a function which takes the `pid` to kill, checks for its parent process, if the parent pid is *explorer.exe*, it terminates the process, if not, kills the process. This should be all happening at the same function to avoid dealing with dynamic pids mentioned in the comments.

I can find the parent process for each `pid` using the following:

```
wmic process get processid,parentprocessid,executablepath|find "process id goes here")
```

I appreciate the help for writing the function.

Comment: FYI, taskkill has two ways of closing a process. With `/F` it tries to open a handle to the process with `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access and calls `TerminateProcess`. Without `/F`, it enumerates the windows of the process and sends `WM_CLOSE`, which the process can handle at its disgression. For a console application, if it's the owner of the console, taskkill sends `WM_CLOSE` to the console window, which in turn instructs the session server (csrss.exe) to send `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to all processes attached to the console. They have 5 seconds to exit gracefully before getting forcefully terminated.

Comment: @ErykSun -Backing off a little bit. Just avoid closing direct child processes of `explorer.exe`. I'm thinking of writing a UDF that takes the `pid`, checks if it's under `explorer.exe` (using this to find the parent ```wmic process get processid,parentprocessid,executablepath|find "process id goes here"```) , then ```if "pid of parent" = "pid of explorer.exe"``` exits and if not, it will kill the process. What I dunno, is how to make this to be recursive. so for instance in this case, `9068` itself won't be closes but its child processes will be. Not sure if this is possible though. is it?

Comment: Does this have to be implemented with just batch scripting (cmd.exe) and command-line utilities such as wmic.exe, tasklist.exe. and taskkill.exe? If not, I would suggest using Python or PowerShell. I'm not a fan of PowerShell, but it has the advantage of already being installed on most Windows systems.

Comment: The main problem with trying to kill a process tree in Windows is that the OS doesn't maintain one. The parent process ID is set when a process is created, but this is static, so descendant branches in the tree can be orphaned, and PIDs of terminated processes in the tree can even be reused by new processes. (The latter can be validated by inspecting creation timestamps. A parent process ID that references a process that was created after the child obviously is not the real parent.)

Comment: You need the shell process for the session. It's not common to replace Explorer, but at startup a process that wants to run as the desktop shell for the session registers itself with the window manager via `SetShellWindowEx`. In C/C++, you can retrieve its top-level desktop window via `GetShellWindow`. Then get its PID via `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. The shell can spawn multiple instances of itself, as Explorer does for file browsers, so you'd have to store its image path from `OpenProcess` and `QueryFullProcessImageNameW` and check whether a parent is the shell by comparing image paths.

Comment: @ErykSun powershell and cmd are both fine.

Comment: not understand sense of question, but formally do this very easy. call `NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation..` and check `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION::InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` before decide kill process or no

Comment: But when enumerating processes to find the children of a target, the creation timestamp has to be checked to confirm that the target is older, due to PID reuse. Modern Windows tries to avoid PID reuse, but there's no guarantee. Traverse the tree using a list of (pid, timestamp) records, beginning with the target. Pop a record from the end. Open a handle. Verify the timestamp. Try to end/terminate the process. Wait on the handle, and close it. If the wait succeeds, take a snapshot of running processes. Append the target's children to the list, excluding processes that are too old. Repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `.bat` script could help understanding parent/child processes and their behaviour…

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo "%~1%~2%~3" | findstr /I "\? \/h \-h">NUL 2>&1
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto :usage 

set "_explorerName=explorer.exe"
set "_NameToKill=%~1"
set "_Terminate=%~2"
set "_KillForce=%~3"

if NOT defined _NameToKill if not [%1]==[] (
  rem debugging 
  set "_NameToKill=CMD.EXE"
  rem debugging: start a child process
  start "" /MIN notepad.exe
)

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G in ('
    TASKLIST /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %_explorerName%"  /FO CSV
') do (
  set "_explorerPID=%%~H"
)
ECHO checking '%_NameToKill%*' as child of %_explorerName% ^(PID=%_explorerPID%^)  
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%G in ('
    wmic process WHERE "Name like '%_NameToKill%%%' and ParentProcessId=%_explorerPID%" get Name^,ParentProcessId^,ProcessId^,Status
') do (
  if NOT "%%H"=="" (
    echo %%G
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%g in ('
        2^>NUL wmic process WHERE "ParentProcessId=%%I" get Name^,ParentProcessId^,ProcessId^,Status
    ') do (
      if NOT "%%h"=="" (
        echo    ProcessId=%%i, ParentProcessId=%%h, %%g child of %%G ^(%%I^)
        if defined _Terminate (
          if /I "%%~g"=="conhost.exe" (
            rem debugging
            taskkill /PID %%i /T
          ) else (
            taskkill /PID %%i %_Terminate% %_KillForce%
          )
          echo(
        )
      )
    )
    echo    ParentProcessId=%%H, ProcessId=%%I, %%G child of %_explorerName% ^(%_explorerPID%^)
    if defined _Terminate (
      taskkill /PID %%I /T
      echo(- 
    )
  )
)
if [%1]==[] goto :usage
:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:usage
  echo USAGE:
  echo %~nx0 -? ^| /? ^| /h ^| -h           this help message
  echo %~nx0                             list all childs of %_explorerName%
  echo %~nx0 ^<processName^> [/T] [/F]     list all childs of a process
  echo %~nx0 ""            [/T] [/F]     a particular test case for cmd.exe
  echo(
  echo Optional parameters /T and /F ^(or -T and -F^): see taskkill /? 
goto :endlocal
```

Answer (score 7):

The parent process has nothing to do with whether the child process is a graphical, console, or service application. If Explorer is the parent, it only means either that Explorer called [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) or that another process called `CreateProcess` or [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) and substituted a handle for Explorer as the child's [`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute#PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS).

For example, if a user double clicks on a .py script icon in Explorer, the shell looks up the file association (e.g. using the internal implementation of the [`IQueryAssociations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nn-shlwapi-iqueryassociations) interface) and executes the corresponding program with the script as an argument, with a command like `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "path\to\script.py"`. If it's executed directly, Explorer calls `CreateProcess` with this command line as an argument. If it's "run as administrator", Explorer sends the request to the Application Information service, which creates the elevated process via `CreateProcessAsUser`, with Explorer set as the parent via the above-mentioned process creation attribute.